# What is use of Sqldependency.ID property?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqldependency

I am using Sql Dependency class to perform an event if any new record inserted on the particular table. 
Here i have achieved what i want exactly, now i would like to know which row has inserted at last and is there any possibilities to find the row id of the last inserted record.

and What is use of **SqlDependency.ID** property It creates GUID.

Answer (score -1):

Answering you second question first: Have a look at `SqlTableDependency`.

Now, for your second question:

I think this ID is used to create a query name in SQL server. Whenever you create a new instance of a SQL dependency it will be create a unique ID for the query which will be used to notify you with updates (update, delete, insert, etc).

When you create a new instance of a `SqlDependency` it will be created, and it will be the same ID as when you get notified from the ONCHANGE method.

I use it when I have multiple properties that get their data from the database, and I want to know which one has been updated.

Finally, it's important to note that this id contains two parts, which you can separate by splitting on `;`. The first one is what you need, and can be converted to a GUID. The second one is for your APPDOMAIN.